# Reversing for loop

Tags: c++

How can I reverse this for loop for the else statement?
I am very open to criticism.

```cpp
int a = 1;
int ans;

ans=a;

int inp;
cout<<"type 1 for ascending and 2 for descending\n \n"<<endl;
cin>>inp;

if (inp==ans) {
    const char* books[6]
        = { "1 Literature", "2 Grammar", "3 Spelling", "4 Short Stories", "5 Alphabet", "6 Punctuations" };

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        cout << books[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
else{?}
```

I tried this and I believe I am very wrong LOL:

```cpp
else{
    const char* books[6]
        = { "1 Literature", "2 Grammar", "3 Spelling", "4 Short Stories", "5 Alphabet", "6 Punctuations" };

    for (int i = 6; i > 0; i--)
        cout << books[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You’re very close. `books[i - 1]` is what you need. Also, there’s no need for `std::endl` after the prompt. `std::cin` and `std::cout` are synchronized; the output gets flushed before the read.

Comment: Since you asked for criticism, always try to indent your code properly. It shouldn't take a few more second when you type them(most IDEs do them automatically anyways), and it can often lead to cleaner logic and more readable code.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep thanks for the criticism I will try to improve on this ^-^

Comment: You don't have to make the loop counter go backwards, just index from the end of the array instead of from the beginning.  Instead of `index_of_first_element + i`  use `index_of_last_element - i`.  In other words, instead of accessing `[i]` access `[5-i]`.  Or, in general, `length_of_array - 1 - i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    int ans = 1;

    int inp{};
    std::cout << "type 1 for ascending and 2 for descending\n\n\n";
    std::cin >> inp;

    std::string books[6] = { "1 Literature", "2 Grammar", "3 Spelling", "4 Short Stories", "5 Alphabet", "6 Punctuations" };
    
    if (inp == ans)
    {
        for (auto& book : books) // another way to do a range based for loop 
        {
            std::cout << book << "\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i{5}; i >= 0; i--) // your answer :)
        {
            std::cout << books[i] << '\n';
        }
    }

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin >> ans; // so my terminal stays open
}
```

This is how you do it. Some tips: declare books outside the for loop no need to redeclare it everytime. Also the index of the last item in an array of size 6 is index 5 so we start there and go until we hit the 0th index and break. also please look into syntax, you must have brackets on a for loop, even if it still compiles no one will like you if they are working with you and it will confuse you. Hope you stick with it C++ is a beautiful language imho.